# zsh substitutions: (P) and ::= operators interaction

Tags: zsh

Can someone explain to me the result of the following script in zsh:

```
#!/bin/zsh
var1=var2
var2=first
var3=second
echo var1="$var1"
echo var2="$var2"
echo var3="$var3"
echo '${${(P)var1::=var3}}'="${${(P)var1::=var3}}"
echo var1="$var1"
echo var2="$var2"
echo var3="$var3"
echo ------------
var1=var2
var2=first
var3=second
echo var1="$var1"
echo var2="$var2"
echo var3="$var3"
echo '${(P)var1::=var3}'="${(P)var1::=var3}"
echo var1="$var1"
echo var2="$var2"
echo var3="$var3"
```

Result:

```
var1=var2
var2=first
var3=second
${${(P)var1::=var3}}=second
var1=var2
var2=var3
var3=second
------------
var1=var2
var2=first
var3=second
${(P)var1::=var3}=var3
var1=var2
var2=var3
var3=second
```

As far as I understand the zsh manual (14.3.2 Rules), the execution of the first section (above ------) should be the following:

1. Point 7 (apply the ::= operator) (set var1 to var3)
2. Point 25 (apply the (P) operator) (dereference var1, get var3)
3. Output the value of var3: 'second'

These steps agree with the following line in the result:

```
${${(P)var1::=var3}}=second
```

But why in the result the following lines appear:

```
var1=var2
var2=var3
```

instead of the expected:

```
var1=var3
var2=first
```

The execution of the second section (below ----) should be (according to the manual):

1. Point 4 (apply the (P) operator) (dereference var1, get var2)
2. Point 7 (apply the ::= operator) (set var2 to var3)
3. Output the value of var2: 'var3'

The results of this section match the explanation above perfectly, so the problem is only with the first section.

Answer (score 0):

The `(P)` applies before the assignment so it's:

1. `${(P)var1::=var3}` -> `${var2::=var3}`
2. -> `${var3}`
3. -> `second`

with `var3` having been assigned to `var2`.

To force the other order, use `${${(P)${var1::=var3}}}`

Note the note in the manual about those rules:

> Note that the Zsh Development
>   Group accepts *no responsibility* for any brain damage which may occur
>   during the reading of the following rules.

Comment: You step 2. does not seem to be right. I have added the second section above to show you the distinction. The result of ${var2::=var3} is not ${var3} but ${var2}, as far as I understand how it works.